# Shiny - Warning: Error in .pointsToMatrix: Wrong length for a vector, should be 2

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a plot that I would like to display on a sidebarPanel.  It indicates the relationship between distance and a performance variable.

The distance variable calculates the distance between 2 points (long, lat) using the distm() function from the geosphere package.

When I run the code in its own r file, I have no problems and the plot renders fine:

```
library(geosphere)

reg_dist <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
reg_zipscore <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
for (i in 1:nrow(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA)) {
  # Longitude first then latitude in the distm function.
  # Obtain the distance between the vendor's centroid and each lat/long that 
  # the vendor has completed work in by meters.
  dist_in_meters <- distm(c(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LONG[i], VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LAT[i]), c(VENDOR_CENTROID$LONG, VENDOR_CENTROID$LAT), fun=distHaversine)
  # Convert the cetntroid-to-zip distance in miles.
  dist_in_miles <- round((dist_in_meters/1000) * 0.621371, digits = 1)
  # Obtain the Zip Score assocaited with the vendor and zip code..
  zip_score <- VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$PCT_ON_TIME[i]
  # Append the distance vector with the latest distance record.
  reg_dist <- rbind(reg_dist, dist_in_miles)
  # Append the Zip Score with the latest zip score record.
  reg_zipscore <- rbind(reg_zipscore, zip_score)
}

# Plot the centroid-to-zip distance and associated zip score.
plot(reg_dist, reg_zipscore)
```

However, when I attempt to run this in a Shiny app, I receive the following error:

'Wrong length for a vector, should be 2'

When I debug, my code throws the error here:

```
dist_in_meters <- distm(c(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LONG[i], VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LAT[i]), c(VENDOR_CENTROID$LONG, VENDOR_CENTROID$LAT), 
                          fun=distHaversine)
```

There is an input in the Shiny app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Vendor Performance Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("vendorInput", "Select Vendor",     unique(as.character(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$VENDORCODE))),
                 plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px")),
    mainPanel(leafletOutput("VEN_MAP", width = "100%", height = 700)))    
)
```

and the server code for the plot is:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    selectedVendor <- reactive({
      VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA[VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$VENDORCODE == input$vendorInput, ]
    })
    reg_dist <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
    reg_zipscore <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)
    for (i in 1:nrow(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA)) {
      # Longitude first then latitude in the distm function.
      # Obtain the distance between the vendor's centroid and each lat/long that the
      #   vendor has completed work in by meters.
      dist_in_meters <- distm(c(VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LONG[i], VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$LAT[i]), c(VENDOR_CENTROID$LONG, VENDOR_CENTROID$LAT), 
                          fun=distHaversine)
      # Convert the cetntroid-to-zip distance in miles.
      dist_in_miles <- round((dist_in_meters/1000) * 0.621371, digits = 1)
      # Obtain the Zip Score assocaited with the vendor and zip code..
      zip_score <- VENDOR_PERFOMANCE_DATA$PCT_ON_TIME[i]
      # Append the distance vector with the latest distance record.
      reg_dist <- rbind(reg_dist, dist_in_miles)
      # Append the Zip Score with the latest zip score record.
      reg_zipscore <- rbind(reg_zipscore, zip_score)
    }

    # Plot the centroid-to-zip distance and associated zip score.
    plot(reg_dist, reg_zipscore)

  })
```

Would someone be willing to explain to me why and a possible solution?

Comment: Likely the root error is not in the code posted. Are any of the variables calculated using any shiny input?

Comment: I added the code to my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot figure out the issue. Try to use `cat` in code to see if those lat longs have correct values.